# Python Checking Win State

Tags: python

I'm writing a basic noughts and crosses game in Python 3.6, I want the output to print only True or False, however the code I've come up with to check the win state:

```
def check_the_lot(board):
    win = check_win_mid_hoz(board)
    win = check_win_bttm_hoz(board)
    win = check_win_top_hoz(board)
    print (win)
```

Will just overwrite the previous checks and just print only the last one? How would I fix this? I cna't figure out how to print only true or only false, and not multiple answers all at once?

Comment: Btw: you do not need any ; in python!

Comment: I offered you an answer easily scalable as it would only require adding the extra functions (verticals and diagonals) to the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
win = check_win_mid_hoz(board) or check_win_bttm_hoz(board) or check_win_top_hoz(board)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, greatly apriciated!!

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept my answer (click the check symbol under the vote button)

Answer (score 0):

When all the functions have the same signature (parameters and outputs) using `any(map())` is a nice solution.

```
def check(board):
    checks = [
        check_win_mid_hoz,
        check_win_bttm_hoz,
        check_win_top_hoz,
    ]
    return any(map(lambda x: x(board), checks))
```

We store the functions without being called in a list. `map()` executes the `lambda` function for every element of checks. This `lambda` function is calling the function with the `board`parameter. `any()` checks if any of the elements evaluates to true.